# hammerspoon remap a key to alt modifier

Tags: hammerspoon

I to remap the ` key so that when I hold it it behave the same way as holding the alt key. For instance holding ` and pressing tab should behave as alt+tab.

I tried this, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "`", function() hs.eventtap.keyStroke({"alt"},"") end)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an [eventtap](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.eventtap.html) and hook into the `keyDown` event. Determine the keycode for the backtick (`50` for my keyboard layout) and post key events to simulate that the alt (option) key was pressed. Finally return `true` to surpress the original key (`).

```
local events = hs.eventtap.event.types
keyboardTracker = hs.eventtap.new({ events.keyDown }, function (e)
  local keyCode = e:getKeyCode()
  if keyCode == 50 then
    hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(hs.keycodes.map.alt,true):post()
    hs.eventtap.event.newKeyEvent(hs.keycodes.map.alt,true):post()
    return true
  end
end)
keyboardTracker:start()
```